# height on select is weird in IE 6

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-6

i am using a jquery plugin called fcbkcomplete which shows up fine in chrome and firefox (see here):

[image]

but when i pull it up in IE6, the height shows up weird in internet explorer 6. (height of main entry box is very tiny).

[image]

i just confirmed its not an overlay issue and definitely a height of input issue as when you add a top margin to the dropdown the height is still small on IE6.  See image below:

[image]

here is my code:

```
       $("#select3").fcbkcomplete({
            json_url: "/Scripts/fcbkcomplete/data.txt",
            addontab: true,
            newel: true,
            firstselected: true,
            height: 2
        });
```

Does anyone know is there is a workaround using css, etc to get IE to work here?

Comment: It's weird because it's IE6 ;)

Comment: @Marwelln - i don't have a choice

Comment: Asking for such functionality in IE6 is like taking a taxi on F1 track. Any ways the only solution for you here is to detect the browser and change the height.

Comment: Since Google dropped support for IE6, most devs have followed in their footsteps. A client who asks for IE6 support is either living in the past or just doesn't know better. It's your responsibility as a developer to enlighten them. The user-base of IE6 is dwindling and gone down below the 12 percent mark according to [Netmarketshare](http://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=3) - So is it worth those 12%, that is in a steady decline, to charge alot more for the final product and give you a headache along the way?

Comment: Does that 12% exclude the pirated copies of Windows XP in Asia?

Comment: @Louis, most likely not. I cannot see how or why they would exclude pirated copies from their statistical data. Ask them?

Comment: @Marcus Ekwall - i appreciate your thoughts but, unfortunately, 80% of my users are on IE 6 and not upgrading any time soon.

Comment: @ooo, why on earth is that? If they are *your* users, can't you upgrade for them? :)

Comment: @Marcus Ekwall - internal company application.  i have no control over desktop

Comment: Anyways, to try and help with your problem. Do you mind sharing the css for that specific input field? Does it have a height set? If not, maybe setting it will solve your problem. Otherwise you can hack some IE6-only css like this: `_height: 16px;`

Comment: @ooo, you might want to inform your boss and/or head of IT that an upgrade to IE8+ (or rather just change to Chrome/Firefox) is long overdue.

Comment: @Marcus Ekwall - preaching to the choir

Comment: @ooo, why preach when you can use [facts](http://www.ie6nomore.com/)?

Comment: @ooo: I tested the [demo page](http://www.emposha.com/demo/fcbkcomplete_2/) in IE6, and it looks correct. You've probably done something to break it in IE6. The easiest way to test this would be if you posted a link to a live page which exhibits the bug in IE6. If that's not an option, you should post the code for a complete HTML page which has the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, Microsoft finally decided it's time to [scrap this archaic beast](http://ie6countdown.com/) of a browser.

Now when both Google and Microsoft are dropping/have dropped support for IE6 its time for your company to do the same. I therefor see this as a valid answer, and so should you and your employer. Do yourself and everyone else a favor and [educate others](http://ie6countdown.com/educate-others.html).

The only valid reason to support IE6 would be when developing for legacy applications (as in your case I guess), but then it's high time to replace this application with something new and modern. In the end, it's all about the money, right?